# Group isomorphic to the direct product of two cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've stumbled across an example which I don't understand and would greatly appreciate some more explanations for:

"We have the group: $U(Z_8, \times )$,

$U(Z_8)\cong C_2 \times C_2$ in which:

$1 \rightarrow (1,1)$

$3 \rightarrow (1,y)$

$5 \rightarrow (x,1)$

$7 \rightarrow (x,y)$

So, I understand that we have the elements 1,3,5,7 in $U(Z_8)$ since they have the gcd = 1 with 8. But how can we see that it's isomorphic to the direct product of $C_2, C_2$? How do we see which elements the cycle group contains? I know that for a cycle group we need to find a generator, but I don't see how that's applicable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, it would be better to identify elements of $C_2\times C_2$ as $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$, and $(1,1)$. Then the group operation in $C_2\times C_2$ is coordinate addition modulo $2$.

So consider the map that sends $1,3,5,7$ to $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$, and $(1,1)$, respectively. Note that the identity in $U$ is sent to the identity in $C_2\times C_2$. We need to show that this map preserves the group operations. For example:

$3\times 5 = 7$ and $(1,0)+(0,1)=(1,1)$

$3\times 7 = 5$ and $(1,0)+(1,1)=(0,1)$

etc..

Alternatively, you can note that $C_2\times C_2$ is the unique group with $4$ elements in which no element has order $4$. So if you can see that no element of $U$ has order $4$ (easy to check) then you know $U$ is isomorphic to $C_2\times C_2$.

Finally, if I have a group $\{e,a,b,c\}$ in which no element has order $4$ (and $e$ is the identity), then *any* bijection from $\{e,a,b,c\}$ to $C_2\times C_2$ sending $e$ to $(0,0)$ is a group isomorphism.

Comment: Thank's a lot! I understand _this_ problem now, but for the future - do you have any specific tips when trying to see if groups are isomorphic? I just studied graph theory where it was pretty easy to check that they had the same number of cycles, edges etc.

Comment: To prove the existence of an isomorphism, you will have to construct one. To prove there isn't one, you can look for different normal subgroups, different orders of the elements, or different homomorphic images. If there are only a few elements like above, then there are also only a few possible groups (cp. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_small_groups). In such cases - like the one above - it is probably sufficient to look for the orders of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the orders of these elements, multiply $3\cdot 5$ and see what you get. Then there are only two groups of order $4$.